# Passing a model class through a checkbox value to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

My test class has a list of test2 classes as a one of its members and when a checkbox is checked, I would like to pass each of the test2 classes back to the controllers.

EDIT: I updated the model from report chooser below to test to match my description above.

model test

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace ImpactIndicator.Models
{
public enum ComparisonSideBySideValue { School, Entry };

public class test
{
    public List<test2> Schools
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportChooser_SchoolInfo"] != null)
            {
                List<ReportSchoolInfo> schools=(List<ReportSchoolInfo>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportChooser_SchoolInfo"];
                schools.OrderBy(t=>t.DistName).ThenBy(t=>t.SchoolName);
                return schools;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportChooser_SchoolInfo"] = value;

        }
    }
}
}
```

model test2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ImpactIndicator.Models
{
public class test2
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public string DistName { get; set; }
    public int SchoolID { get; set; }
    public int DistID { get; set; }
    public int? SchoolLevelID { get; set; }
}
}
```

view

```
int counter1 = 0;

foreach (var item in ViewBag.ReportSchools)
{
    if (counter1 % 2 == 0)
    {
                    @:<tr>
                }

                <td>

                @{
    bool isSelected = false;
    if (ViewBag.ReportChooser.Schools != null)
    {
        foreach (var selSchoolID in ViewBag.ReportChooser.Schools)
        {
            if (item.ToString() == selSchoolID)
            {
                isSelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    if (isSelected)
    {
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Schools' id='Schools' value="@item" class="rptschool" checked="checked" /> @:@item.DistName/@item.SchoolName &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    }
    else
    {
                        <input type='checkbox' name='Schools' id='Schools' value="@item" class="rptschool" /> @:@item.DistName/@item.SchoolName &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    }

                    }

                @*@Html.CheckBox(schoolName, new { @class = "rptschool" }) @item.DistName/@item.SchoolName &nbsp;&nbsp; *@
                </td>

    if (counter1 % 2 == 1 || counter1 == ViewBag.SchoolCount - 1)
    {
                    @:</tr>
                }

    counter1++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the same name on your checkboxes so you can do

```
Request.Form["Schools"].ToString()
```

on your controller and this will give you a list of all checked checkboxes from that list

Comment: okay, thanks.  Is there a way to save these values to the List<test2> in the test class? something like the below?

      test t = new test();

      foreach (test2 te in Request.Form["Schools"])
      {
           t.test2.add(te);
      }

Comment: yes,  the request.form will bring in 1,2,... so you will need to split it test t = new test(); foreach (test2 te in Request.Form["Schools"].ToString().split(',')) { t.test2.add(te); }

Comment: It's telling me that it cannot convert type 'string' to 'ImpactIndicator.Models.test2' for the foreach code line

Comment: the split will give a list of strings.  so change the foreach to be string temp in request... then for your add you will need to do t.test2.add(new test2 { field = temp })

Comment: okay, what's saved into Request.Form["Schools"] is a group of selections of class test2.  If I am correct, in your example above, the field is a member in the class test2 and the temp is each split string from Request.Form["Schools"], so I would be setting one of the members of the class test2 to a string representation of one of the selections of class test2

Comment: When i write to the screen what is saved into Request.Form["Schools"], if I select 2 checkboxes, it shows:
ImpactIndicator.Models.ReportSchoolInfo,ImpactIndicator.Models.ReportSchoolInfo

Comment: you need to do a .ToString() on the Request.Form.  What you should be seeing is a list of the id's of the selected checkboxes "1, 2, 4, etc"

Comment: what I am passing into the checkbox value is @item from my foreach statement "foreach (var item in ViewBag.ReportSchools)".

ViewBag.ReportSchools is being set in the controller as below:
ObjectResult<RptGetSchoolsByUserAndIndicator_Result> getSchools = db.RptGetSchoolsByUserAndIndicator(indicatorID, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
List<ReportSchoolInfo> reportSchools = getSchools.Select(s => new ReportSchoolInfo { SchoolID = s.SchoolID, SchoolName = s.SchoolName, DistID = s.DistID, DistName = s.DistName, SchoolLevelID = s.SchoolLevelID }).ToList();
ViewBag.ReportSchools = reportSchools;

Comment: I am not using an ID for the checkbox value, but am trying to pass the class test2 as the value for the checkbox.

Comment: you can't pass a class.  The only way to pass a class back to the controller is to put every field in that class into a for helper.  you best option will be to pass the id back and query for the class that goes with it

Comment: what about for a class that doesn't have a unique identifier?

Comment: if you can, add a unique identifier.  if not you are going to have to get creative.  maybe put a couple fields into the value that together will make it unique

Comment: Very helpful and promptly. Thanks Matt!